# In service cloud how to get the chat window data in omnichannel flow

Tags: visual-workflow, servicecloud, omnichannel

How to get the chat window data in omnichannel flow. In my chat window user-given input, I want to get the chatbot first-Name and Subject on the omnichannel flow.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vVkYQ04Li3BrJFWxQ1A66xeWhOyCSp_y/view?usp=sharing

[image: Need to get the pre-chat data on the omnichannel flow.]

Note: For pictures check the above link, face difficulties uploading pictures on StackExchange.

Is it possible to get data from the chatbot to omnichannel flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to access the pre-chat details from incoming chats inside your Omni-Flow.

The pre-chat data for chats is stored in a Salesforce Object 'ConversationContextEntry' and you can set up your Omni-Flow to get the concerned data using the steps outlined in [Create the prechat article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_create_variable_prechat.htm&type=5)

> To build a flow that routes chats based on information captured in a pre-chat form, add a prechat record collection variable. Set up the variable to pull pre-chat details from the Conversation Context Entry object.